# NoReverseMatch in Django with namespace

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I can't do a reverse in Django without throwing a NoReverseMatch, even though the pages will load if no reverse is done.
Here is the relevant code:

main/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(^$)|(^admin/)',include('example_admin.urls',namespace='example_admin')),
)
```

example_admin/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from example_admin import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

example_admin/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'example_admin/index.hmtl', context)
```

And everything works well, until I put this line in my index.html template

```
<a href="{% url 'example_admin:index' %}">LNK</a>
```

I get this error:
`Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(^$)|(^admin/)$']`

I have tried in a django shell as well, using reverse('index') and reverse('example_admin:index') and neither worked for me.

Comment: from the shell I ran resolve('/admin/') and I got ResolverMatch(func=<function index at 0x7f3d552c5500>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='index', app_name='None', namespace='example_admin')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changeing the link in main/urls.py from

```
url(r'(^$)|(^admin/)',include('example_admin.urls',namespace='example_admin')),
```

to

```
url(r'^admin/',include('example_admin.urls',namespace='example_admin')),
url(r'^$',include('example_admin.urls',namespace='example_admin')),
```

I guess it really didn't like my regex OR statement, does anyone know why?

Comment: Simply because this [hasn't been implemented yet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L97).