# Django linking to generic.DetailView page but page contents is the same as the generic.ListView page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I've encountered an issue where I've created a list view and each item in it has a detail view. When I click the item in the list view, the link in the searchbar changes from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/articles/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/articles/[UUID]`, but the actual page contents does not change. Even though I am supposedly in the detail view and I have a detail view html file, the displayed contents is still the list view.

articles.html:

```
{% extends 'head.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="flex items-center justify-center text-6xl">Articles</h1>
    <br>
    {% if articles %}
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
            <div class="posts">
                {% for article in articles reversed %}
                    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <div class="article_box">
                            <img src="{{ article.article_cover_image.url }}" alt="img">
                            <div class="article_box_sub">
                                <div>{{ article.article_title }}</div>
                                <div class="text-xs">{{ article.article_date_and_time }} UTC</div>
                                <div class="text-xs">
                                    Written by 
                                    {% for author in article.article_author.all %}
                                        {% if not forloop.last and forloop.revcounter0 > 1 %}
                                            <span class="link_light">{{author}}</span>,
                                        {% elif forloop.revcounter0 == 0 and forloop.counter0 > 0 %}
                                            and <span class="link_light">{{author}}</span>
                                        {% elif forloop.revcounter0 == 1 and forloop.counter0 > 1 %}
                                            <span class="link_light">{{author}}</span>,
                                        {% else %}
                                            <span class="link_light">{{author}}</span>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {% for tag in article.article_tags.all %}
                                        <div class="tag text-xs">{{tag}}</div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    <div class="tag text-xs">{{ article.get_article_timespan_start_display }}-{{ article.get_article_timespan_end_display }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

article_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'head.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Title: {{ article.title }}</h1>
    <p>Help</p>
{% endblock %}
```

article_detail.html currently is just placeholder content to see if I can make it load.

views.py:

```
class Article_List_View(generic.ListView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'articles.html'
    paginate_by = 21

class Article_Detail_View(generic.DetailView):
    def article_detail_view(request, primary_key):
        try:
            article = Article.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Article does not exist.')
        
        return render(request, 'catalog/article_detail.html', context={'article' : article})
```

urls.py:

```
path('articles/', views.Article_List_View.as_view(), name='articles'),
path('articles/<str:pk>', views.Article_List_View.as_view(), name='article-detail')
```

File structure:

[image]

How do I get the page to load properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to point the right endpoint to access the details of article.
as you registered the endpoint is

```py
path('articles/<str:pk>', views.Article_List_View.as_view(), name='article-detail')
```

and the articles.html should be:

```html
{% for article in articles reversed %}
   <a href="{% url 'articles:article-detail' article.uuid %}"> <!-- specify your endpoint here -->
      <div class="article_box">
           ...
      </div>
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

you need to adjust Article_Detail_View class since you use primary_key instead of pk as your endpoint registered.
it should be:

```py
class Article_Detail_View(generic.DetailView):
    def article_detail_view(request, pk): # change primary_key to pk
        try:
            article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Article does not exist.')
        
        return render(request, 'catalog/article_detail.html', context={'article' : article})
```

that's all you need.

Comment: When I plug this code in I get `NoReverseMatch at /catalog/articles/` saying `'articles' is not a registered namespace`

Comment: you need to hit the right endpoint, you can check to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467418/noreversematch-in-django-with-namespace

Comment: Forgive me, but I have no idea what you mean by that. The link you provided uses `url` which no longer exists as of Django 4.0 and has been replaced with `re_path`, but when trying to do what that link suggests, it doesn't work and I get more errors.

Comment: ```url``` here is not in django urls.py but in jinja or template html. you can change from ```<a href="{% url 'articles:article-detail' article.uuid %}">``` to ```<a href="{{ settings.BASE_URL }}/{{article.uuid}}">```